# Execute threads in parrallel, but calling events in the same order

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I have a scenario where I have a queue of data to process. All the data gets read into memory and stored into a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` by one thread while another thread starts dequeueing and processing data. T being a custom class with a large amount of data to process.

The reader threads fills one side of the queue, while the processor thread works down the other side of the queue. With two threads, this works perfectly. Processing the data takes about 4 times more work/time than loading the data into memory. So I've been trying to increasing the amount of processing threads. The problem comes that the processed data needs to be SAVED in the same order as it's read. Obviously having multiple threads processing different data in parallel means that they won't finish at the same time. The threads do read the data in order because of ConcurrentQueue and they Dequeue the data in the corrrect order, but I haven't found a way to synchronize the thread's "save" function in a way that insures each thread will "save" in the same order they Dequeued.

I know .NET contains a load of thread helpers, and I've looked at things like Monitor, and Barrier, but they're so wildly different that I'm not sure which helper class or which method would work best.

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Shape your stuff so it can work unordered?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I'm reading a sequential file that needs to be saved sequentially after processing.

Comment: But nothing prevents you to process/save 'chunks' of it, right?

Comment: Just add a sequence number to the data.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a TPL DataFlow Example

DataFlow has a few advantages

1. It can deal with both synchronous and asynchronous workloads.
2. You can create larger pipelines.
3. Supports Task Schedulers, and cancellations tokens.
4. Can run perpetually, or force to complete.
5. Each block can support multiple producers and consumers

It does have some disadvantages through

1. It's a bit of learning curve for the uninitiated.
2. It's designed around a pipeline, not linear collections *per se*, so using them can be a little unintuitive.
3. Creating your own custom blocks will require a deep dive in Stephen Toub's Twisted TPL brain.
4. It's not as light as other producer consumer frameworks, however it makes up for it with flexibility

**Example**

```
// multi threaded Consumer
var processor = new TransformBlock<Data, Data>(
   ProcessAsync,
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() 
   {
      EnsureOrdered = true, 
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3

   });

var saver = new ActionBlock<Data>(
   SaveAsync, 
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
   {
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, 
      SingleProducerConstrained = true
   });

processor.LinkTo(saver,new DataflowLinkOptions() {PropagateCompletion = true});

// Producer
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Queueing : {i}");
   await processor.SendAsync(new Data() {Id = i});
}

processor.Complete();
await saver.Completion;
```

**Workloads**

```
public static Random r = new Random();
private static async Task<Data> SaveAsync(Data arg)
{
   await Task.Delay(r.Next(100, 1000));
   Console.WriteLine($"Saving : {arg.Id}");
   return arg;
}
private static async Task<Data> ProcessAsync(Data arg)
{
   await Task.Delay(r.Next(100, 1000));
   Console.WriteLine($"Processing : {arg.Id}");
   return arg;
}
```

**Output**

```
Queueing : 0
Queueing : 1
Queueing : 2
Queueing : 3
Queueing : 4
Queueing : 5
Queueing : 6
Queueing : 7
Queueing : 8
Queueing : 9
Queueing : 10
Queueing : 11
Queueing : 12
Queueing : 13
Queueing : 14
Processing : 2
Processing : 3
Processing : 0
Processing : 1
Processing : 4
Saving : 0
Processing : 5
Processing : 8
Saving : 1
Processing : 7
Processing : 6
Processing : 10
Saving : 2
Processing : 9
Processing : 11
Processing : 12
Processing : 13
Saving : 3
Processing : 14
Saving : 4
Saving : 5
Saving : 6
Saving : 7
Saving : 8
Saving : 9
Saving : 10
Saving : 11
Saving : 12
Saving : 13
Saving : 14
```

Disclaimer, there are many other ways, for instance Reactive Extensions, or just regular TPL and loops, all have advantages and disadvantages, and some may suit your use case more than others. This was just an example basic example of a DataFlow Pipeline.

Comment: Although that is an amazing answer, and I actually tried to fit my code around it, it doesn't work in my particular scenario because the processing function "exits" at different point depending and how deep it needs to process the block of data, and at each exit, it calls an event which the result (which doesn't have the same class nor inherited base). And its those different "points" I need to synchronize. I'll keep this in mind if I see a way I can rework my code to "complete" at the same endpoint.

Comment: @jscarle yeah I feared that would the case.... Maybe you could edit your question with a bit more detail so others don't fall into a similar trap. I might be able to write a different answer based on the edit. Good luck

Comment: I'll have to take the time to elaborate. Thanks for the effort.